# Pages don't update, clearing cache doesn't help

Tags: caching, nodes

I have a site on Drupal 6. A week ago I've update some content and the changes are visible when I'm logged in, but when opening the site as an anonymous user, I still get the old content. I've tried it on multiple computers and multiple browsers and I've flushed all caches. It seems that the site's content is cached somewhere... What can I do about it?

Comment: Do you have Redis, Varnish, etc. enabled?

Comment: No, I'm not using any additional caching/acceleration utilities